# How to implement Android Calendar app's Day-View?

Tags: android, calendar

[Android Calendar App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZXFZ.png)

I need to be able to implement a view similar to the day-view in the Calendar App.

My questions are:

1. How can I overlay a button encompassing multiple rows.
2. If two events overlap, how do I dynamically add a
   column similar to the picture above.

Comment: ...were you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a solution here http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Comment: If you don't mind my asking. Which were the specific classes that dealt with the week view. I am looking through them and I can't seem to find any classes related to week view!

Comment: @Andy, do you mean classes related to day view? Because I'm looking for the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: @JaKXz yea. But honestly it was more trouble that it was worth. I ended up creating my own version with `ListView` that worked out nicely. I didn't have to worry about performance because it was already built in. So just worried about the logic in placing the views. I haven't gotten a chance but I'll be putting something in github.